# access to elements inside a reactive function

Tags: r, shiny, reactive-programming

If I put some element is reactive function which I need them further down the code How could I recall them, Example :

```
        library(shiny)
library(data.table)
library(formattable)
library(tables)
ui <- fluidPage(
      fileInput(inputId =  "File",label =  "Upload file...",accept=c("zip","text")),
      tableOutput("AEP")
)


server <- function(input, output){
  options(shiny.maxRequestSize=50*1024^2) 
  #output$AEP <- renderTable({
  data1 <- reactive({  
    infile=input$File

    if (is.null(infile))
      return(NULL)

    report_list <- c("Park result.txt",
                     "Park result minus",
                     "Park result plus")
    temp_files <- unzip(infile$datapath)
    temp_files <- temp_files[grepl(paste(report_list, collapse = "|"), temp_files)]

    T=length(temp_files)
    t1=3*c(1:(T/3))

    t2=c(1:T)
    t2=t2[-t1]
    p=c();for(i in 1:T){p[[i]]=c()}
    for(i in 1:(length(t1))){p[[t1[i]]]=read.table(temp_files[t1[i]],skip=1,sep=";")}
    for(i in 1:(length(t2))){p[[t2[i]]]=read.table(temp_files[t2[i]],skip=2,sep=";")}
    Installed_Power=v=park=c();for(i in 1:T/3){park[[i]]=v[[i]]=c()}

    for(i in 1:(T/3)){
      park[[i]]=as.matrix(cbind(p[[1+(i-1)*3]],p[[2+(i-1)*3]],p[[3+(i-1)*3]]))
    }
    #Power output :
    y=c();for(i in 1:T/3){y[[i]]=c()}
    power=Ave.A=Ave.k=AD=c()
    for (i in 1:(T/3)){ 


        y[[i]]=park[[i]][,153][3:length(park[[i]][,153])]
        y[[i]]=gsub("\\,","",y[[i]])
        y[[i]]=as.numeric(y[[i]])
        power[i]=sum(y[[i]])/1000
        Ave.A[i]=mean(as.numeric(park[[i]][3:length(park[[i]][,162]),162]))
        Ave.k[i]=mean(as.numeric(park[[i]][3:length(park[[i]][,163]),163]))
        AD[i]=mean(as.numeric(park[[i]][3:length(park[[i]][,200]),200]))
    }
  })
  output$AEP <- renderTable({
    df <- data1()
    df <-as.data.frame(df)
    AEP=data.table(df$power,df$Ave.k,df$Ave.A,df$AD)
  })

}
shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

now I have `reac ()`, as reactive function. What if in another reactive or render function I need just `T` value ? can I access it by `$` like `reac()$`T ??
The above mentioned code returns the error :

```
Warning: Error in data.table: column or argument 1 is NULL
```

Code is working If I do not use the reactive function and just put the render function instead ! I do that because I need at the end download the result as pdf file. (the AEP table)
Also what should I do if I want to use AEP table in R markdown ?

Answer (score 1):

This reproducible example shows how the reactive data frame can be accessed just like any other data frame in a Shiny app.  Without being able to reproduce the question, it's hard to say what's really going on with your app.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Test Reactive Dataframe"),
  mainPanel(textInput("test", "EnterTextHere"),
            tableOutput("test1"),
            tableOutput("test2")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  df1 <- reactive({
    data.frame(id = 1:length(input$test), input = input$test)
  })

  output$test1 <- renderTable({
    df1()$input
  })

  output$test2 <- renderTable({
    df1()[,1:2]
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always define reac() as a dataframe in either another reactive or render function.

Try:

```
output$table <- renderTable({
  df <- reac()
  df <- as.data.frame(df)
  df$T
})
```

Comment: It does not work :Warning: Error in data.table: column or argument 1 is NULL